# QtOpenGL - shared OpenGL context

Tags: python, qt, opengl, qtopengl

I have an `Qt4` + `OpenGL` + `Python` application which generates geometry and then draws it on `QGLWidget`.

```
class GLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):

   def initializeGL(self):
       (...)
       self.scene.buildScene() #this generates geometry and creates OpenGL Lists

   def paintGL(self):
       (...)
       self.scene.renderScene() # this calls glCallList on every object
```

And this works fine. The problem is that geometry generation can take from seconds to even minutes depending on input. In this time no Qt window appears, because the application is stuck in `initializeGL()`

I've tried to avoid this "lag" by creating another thread with additional OpenGL context with shared resources:

```
class GLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      (...)
      self.buildingThread = threading.Thread(target=self.buildingThreadFunc)

   def buildingThreadFunc(self):
      self.buildFormat = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
      self.buildingContext = QtOpenGL.QGLContext(self.buildFormat)
      self.buildingContext.create(self.context()) #This returns False
      self.buildingContext.device() #This returns None
      self.buildingContext.initialized() #This returns False

      self.scene.buildScene() #And finnally this fails because 
                              #there is no context to call `glGenLists`

   def initializeGL(self):
      (...)
      self.buildingThread.start()

   def paintGL(self):
      (...)
      self.scene.renderScene() #Here, every element on scene shall successively appears during geometry creation
```

The core problem is that `QGLContext::create` returns False, but I don't know why.

Furthermore : Is my idea with another thread and context correct? Will it work? I guess there can be a problem with `glGenLists` and painting on `QGLWidget` at the same time, but I hope at least other widgets to be "responsive".

Answer (score 1):

Years ago [I've read this blog post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/06/03/threaded-opengl-in-4-8/), explaining how to use multiple render threads. I had a GL loading widget which I was showing while behind the scene, another QGLWidget was starting.
Based on the blog post I made a demo that showed dozens of my loading widgets, all starting concurrently.

Also take a look at this example:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-demos-glhypnotizer-example.html